# Cant get mediaqueries to work because of document width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Im creating a responsive site and i didn't understand why my document width is 980px, even tho im in braves inspector tool with a responsive size of 428x807. If i set a media query like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    h4 {
        color:blue;
    }
}
```

Should this not say that if the screen is less than 576px its supposed to be colored blue? How come the inspector and the actual size of document is different?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a special mate tag to force browsers, in particular mobile ones, to be real about their viewport widths. This tag is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and should be included in the head of your document. Historically mobile devices would pretend to have desktop sizes since websites weren't expected at all to be rendered at such small screen sizes when mobile devices were first popularised. We are talking about the blackberry era here and it was deemed more appropriate to render a website extremely zoomed out on mobile so that you could zoom in as needed and at least see all the content as intended. I hope this is your problem because otherwise I can't think of another explanation.